# Alternate version of Through the Eye of a Needle by Hal Clement?

Tags: through-the-eye-of-a-needle

Just got a Christmas copy of *Through the Eye of a Needle*.

I remembered reading a library copy years ago. Had forgotten most of it, but seemed to remember it ending with Jenny, romantic interest, demanding a copy of Hunter...and an implication that Bob and Jenny would marry.

My current copy, paperback first edition, doesn't end that way but just has a pretty blah ending with Maeta, romantic interest two, going back to filing library books.

Was wondering if Clement might have fixed some issues with the first edition and written a different version. In both cases, the book seems less memorable and special than *Needle*.  But I got the impression that first edition of successor was worse than my possibly imagined alternate edition successor.

Comment: I have an old copy. Will check it when I get back home in a couple of days.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ending I have ([1978 edition](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?238245)) is:

> "Not at first," the alien admitted, "but later on I should have swapped around to other hosts. There were Bob's parents, and the doctor, who knew about me."
>
> "Would you need that many? Wouldn't just back and forth between two people be all right?"
>
> "I'd think so, but I'm not sure. I could ask Xeno. But isn't it rather academic now, anyway?"
>
> "Not entirely," Maeta said. "You find out—and make sure when that cold-blooded molecule manipulator is going to be through with Bob, while you're at it. I think I can hold hands with him long enough for you two to get that much of a message across. Now think over those lessons in biochem that Xeno ordered you to memorize; I have book work to do."

A [Google books search](https://books.google.ca/books?id=f2czAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=through+the+eye+of+a+needle&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjDmcvhwreDAxWQtokEHbFDCXgQ6AF6BAgEEAI#v=snippet&q=%22book%20work%22&f=false) of the 2011 e-book shows the same ending text.  (Note how the text "book work to do." is immediately followed by "If you've enjoyed...")

According to [ISFDb](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1480) these are the only 2 major releases of this book; the [1979 entry](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?502113) is described merely as "Second Printing: February 1979."  The separate entry appears to be from an ISBN update that goes with the increase in the cover price from US$1.75 (first printing) to US$1.95 (second printing); the contents are identical.  (Even to the "About the Author" page which for some reason ISFDb only notes in the second edition, even though it is also present in the first.)

It's entirely possible that in the years since you first read it, you conflated Maeta and Jenny, and built up Maeta's implication that she wanted to share Hunter with Bob into a more concrete expression of romantic interest.

Comment: Thanks. Will wait a tad before accepting. You're probably right.

Comment: This [1978 first paperback edition](https://archive.org/details/througheyeofneed0000clem) on Archive.org has the same ending; https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmLsp.png